# Check the conditions between two select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-insert

If either one table or both tables has zero records in the table, we need to put them into a temp table.

How do we write the below statement in SQL Server.

```
select Total
into #t1 
from
(    
    select Total = 'The data did not load into customers table'
    from 
    (
        select count(*) as total
        from customers  
        having count(*) = 0
    ) a

    OR

    select Total= 'The data did not load into Employees table'
    from 
    (
        select count(*) as total
        from Employees  
        having count(*)=0
    ) a
) b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `not exists` combined with a `union all` should do the trick:

```
select 'The data did not load into Customers table' Error
into #t1
where not exists (select 1 from Customers)
union all
select 'The data did not load into Employees table' Error
where not exists (select 1 from Employees);
```

Comment: @Akhira thank you for awarding me the answer... please also go back through your old questions and award answers where you have received a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I followed you correctly, you could use `union all` as follows:

```
insert into #t1(total)
select 'The data did not load into customers table' from customers having count(*) = 0
union all
select 'The data did not load into employees table' from employees having count(*) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks you GMB, this helps!